# What is the word for "something that is true, but misleading"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

A person in the news recently stated that he was a "Vietnam era veteran". This misled EVERYBODY into thinking he was a Vietnam veteran (and newspapers widely reprinted that he was). But no, he merely served in the armed forces while the Vietnam war was going on, but never participated.

Is there a word for that specific kind of technically-true-but-grossly-misleading claim?

BTW I'm very liberal this is not meant to be about politics but strictly language usage, there's no doubt in my mind that calling yourself a "Vietnam era veteran" is meant to convey a false impression.

Comment: ...in other words, it is only misleading to those who have not read the history. And I take exception to the the statement : " _merely_  served in the armed forces while the Vietnam war was going on, but never participated" That is a gross misrepresentation of how war is conducted. What most civilians never understand is that many more staff work in _support_ than as combatants at  the front lines: that does not make their efforts any less important. Remember Beirut.

Comment: What's wrong with ***misleading***  And for a less contentious example:  I never gave him a cent.  (All the money I gave was to his wife, and she gave it to him for me)

Comment: an idiom is bending the truth ... me thinks one word will be difficult

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no word to describe , _specifically_ "a word for _that specific kind_ of technically-true-but-grossly-misleading claim?"

Comment: To expand on @Cascabel's comments - the statement is not misleading in any way. And to suggest it was intended to mislead is ridiculous. It is a perfectly understood term among those of the Vietnam War generation. It is a category that accrues all kinds of benefits from college GI bills to VA benefits etc. Serving in time of war is different from serving in time of peace, benefit wise. More importantly, there is simply no better way to say that. So please revise the example in your question.

Comment: I think the example could be made clearer. Is the **intention** to deceive? Is the intention not to deceive but the misinterpretation is **convenient** and not corrected? There may even be less contentious examples which demonstrate the behaviour asked about.

Comment: I disagree significantly with the context of your question. As an autistic, I've found my exact use of speech to be twisted into falsehoods by listeners and then blamed for lying on multiple occasions. Just because somebody doesn't have the necessary attention to notice a distinction does not mean there was any attempt to deceive that person. However, the basic question is a good one, as there are many who do try to deceive with that method.

Comment: I think there's a clear difference between a *Vietnam veteran* and a *Vietnam-era veteran*. The latter certainly doesn't mean they were involved with Vietnam in any way. And even if the phrase were *Vietnam veteran*, that wouldn't mean they saw combat. (Assuming that's what you mean by *participated*.) So, it's not at all clear who's being misled about what here or even if there's anything misleading going on at all. You certainly can't say *everybody*, because that's simply not true.

Answer (score 2):

Note, I'm not making any judgement on the person you are referring to (the Vietnam era veteran) in giving this answer. This answer refers to saying something which is technically true but may mislead.

equivocation

The definitions generally seem to go something like "the use of equivocal language, or the act of equivocating", so I'll give the meaning of equivocal.

> equivocal
>   1. capable of varying interpretations; ambiguous
>   2. deliberately misleading or vague; evasive
>   3. of doubtful character or sincerity; dubious
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/equivocal)
>
> 1a : subject to two or more interpretations and usually used to
>   mislead or confuse
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocal)
>
> 1.allowing the possibility of several different meanings, as a word or phrase, especially with intent to deceive or misguide; susceptible of
>   double interpretation; deliberately ambiguous:
>  [Random House
>   Unabridged (dictionary.com)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/equivocal)

Note that many dictionaries, such as Oxford Living Dictionaries only mention statements possible to different interpretations, but don't specifically mention misleading:

> 1.Open to more than one interpretation; ambiguous.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/equivocal)

Some people use the term half-truth for this.

> half-truth
>  A statement, especially one intended to deceive, that
>   omits some of the facts necessary for a full description or
>   account.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/half-truth)

But I don't like this term. I think most dictionaries define is as only partly true. However the Wikipedia article states:

> The statement might be partly true, the statement may be totally true but only part of the whole truth...
>  [Half-truth Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-truth)

An example given in the article:

> After being stopped for drunk driving, the inebriated driver proclaims
>   "I only had a couple of beers" in slurred speech. The driver may have
>   also consumed alcoholic drinks other than beer, and the "beers" may
>   have been large bottles as opposed to the usual contents of a
>   normal-sized can, bottle, or glass.
>   [half-truth (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-truth)

"I only had a couple of beers" seems to me to be completely true, though misleading.

However many dictionaries define half-truth as only partly true. And I really don't want create a philosophical debate about what is truth (eg., lying by omission), let's just leave it at that, that some people use this term, however much of a misnomer "half-truth" may seem to be.

Comment: Most of the uses of half-truth that I remember having heard were like that.  Entirely true, but deliberately misleading.  My ex-wife refers to these as lies that are true, which seems to me like a better term for them.

Answer (score 0):

for a single word (not misleading - the best), **misinform** [TFD](https://mis%C2%B7in%C2%B7form%20%20(m%C4%ADs%E2%80%B2%C4%ADn-f%C3%B4rm%E2%80%B2)%20tr.v.%20mis%C2%B7in%C2%B7formed,%20mis%C2%B7in%C2%B7form%C2%B7ing,%20mis%C2%B7in%C2%B7forms%20To%20provide%20with%20incorrect%20information.) or misguide, misdirect.

> to provide with incorrect information.

As in:

> A person in the news recently stated that he was a "Vietnam era
>   veteran" misinforming EVERYBODY.

Comment: You don't seem to grasp the point. A _Vietnam vet_ was "in-country". A Vietnam _era_ vet served in the military during the conflict. Both were on "active duty".

Comment: I was in the carrier navy - never set foot on land and was rarely actually in the combat zone (carrier based) - but me and my shipmates call ourselves gulf war vets. But to re-assess and be apolitical, i have edited my answer.

Comment: In British English, "misinform" means to give ["false or inaccurate information"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/misinform), not to give true, accurate information which is misleading. Your suggestion of "misinform" is therefore likely to mislead the OP...